# Как связать телеграмм бот и кибербезопасность?

Tags: python, безопасность

Мне нужно написать проект, у меня есть почти готовый, но нужно какой-то продукт. Телеграмм ботов я могу писать, любых, но нужна именно тема кибербезопасности, если взять какой-то другой телеграмм бот и под него сделать проект, то это нужно все сначала. Необязательно, конечно, телеграмм ботов, но это самое лёгкое и быстрое. Я думал насчёт каких-то команд, связанных с рекомендациями по кибербезопасности, но лучше тогда сделать какую-то распечатку. Что думаете?

Answer (score 3):

Ну, например, телеграм бот, который учит кибербезопасности, сначала лекционные материалы, а потом тест по пройденному материалу. Реализовать саму подачу информации с помощью видео, изображений, текста. Переходы между слайдами с помощь `inline` кнопок "назад", "вперед". Вести базу пользователей, тест так же с помощью `inline` кнопок организовать, лучшие результаты записывать в базу данных.

Comment: Спасибо за уделенное время

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать бота, который будет проверять файлы на наличие вирусов, отправляя их на VirusTotal, например. Ты ему скармливаешь файл или ссылку, а он дает ответ на наличие или отсутствие вредоносов.

Answer (score 0):

Напиши бота, который будет хэшировать твое сообщение разными хэшами, можно и самописными, чтобы точно никто не вскрыл))